# Create another Widget when OnTap() is triggered

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Does anyone know how to generate a new widget in Flutter when `OnTap()` is triggered?

In my case, I want to create a new column inside a container, when the column icon is pressed.

The icon is wrapped with an `InkWell()`.

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    print("Create Column in another Container");
  },
  child: Column(
    children: const [
      Icon(
        Icons.view_agenda,
        color: iconGreyColor,
        size: 20.0,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

The Goal shut look like this.

```dart
    Container(child: Column(children:[]),)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to create this `column` multiple times? e.g. create a specific widget each time the user pressed that button. is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Main part:

...widget.widgets -> *spread operator* .whenever ontap pressed.the array will get new element and set state will update the widget.

```
InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  widget.widgets.add(Container(
                    height: 49,
                    child: new Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "hi",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ));
                });
                print("Create Column in another Container");
              },
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.view_agenda,
                    size: 20.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

---

```
 Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 10.0,
          right: 10.0,
        ),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 150,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [...widget.widgets],
        ),
      )
```

**sample code**

```
void main() => runApp(MyHomePage());

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Page0(),
    );
  }
}

class Page0 extends StatefulWidget {
  final widgets = [];

  @override
  _Page0State createState() => _Page0State();
}

class _Page0State extends State<Page0> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 25.0,
          ),
          Center(
              child: Text(
            "macintosh_app",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48),
          )),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50.0,
          ),
          Center(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  widget.widgets.add(Container(
                    height: 49,
                    child: new Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "hi",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ));
                });
                print("Create Column in another Container");
              },
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.view_agenda,
                    size: 20.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 25.0,
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 10.0,
              right: 10.0,
            ),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 150,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [...widget.widgets],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this using `StatefulWidget()`. Create a `List<Widget>` outside your build of `StatefulWidget()` and inside your `InkWell()` append new `Widget()` you want to add and call `setState((){})`

```
class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget {
  const YellowBird({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
  State<YellowBird> createState() => _YellowBirdState();
}

class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird> {
List<Widget> myWidgetList = [
  Text("hello"),
];
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("Create Column in another Container");
          myWidgetList.add(Text("hello 2"));
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: Column(
          children: const [
            Icon(
              Icons.view_agenda,
              size: 20.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Column(
        children: myWidgetList,
      ),
    ],
  );
 }
}
```

You can run same code here [Link](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&309c4d703cc18a425bccd278866201b0)

Answer (score 0):

Inside `OnTap()`, you can pass a function that can create a Widget.

e.g.

```dart
    Widget buildContainer(){ return Container(child: Text("Stack Overflow"))}
```

Insert this function before your build method and then call it during the `OnTap()` event. You can, of course, modify the Container according to your exact requirements.

The important thing to understand here is that you can create functions with any permissible return type, even a specific Widget, this is especially useful when you want to create multiple identical widgets, as it reduces redundant code.